# Couldn't resolve host 'api.sparkpost.com' in laravel CurlFactory

Tags: php, laravel, curl

Everything was working fine just this  morning and suddenly my app stopped sending email just now. And the app is very much depenedent on Mails to work. This is a live site that gave a problem and it is made on Laravel PHP framework v 5.2.
Also the same error is occuring while using mailgun API, which was also working till yesterday.

[image: This is the image while using sparkpost API]
[image: This is the image while using mailgun API]

Comment: please check is that installed curl package and enabled curl extension?

Comment: Till a few minutes ago it was working so yes it is installed

Comment: If this is your personal server,then fine.But if shared,then please contact with provider.I think somehow provider disabled curl.

Comment: please checkout the **posibilites** for this error https://www.google.co.in/search?q=curl+could+not+resolve+host&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=j08QWOqxGeHn8Af59KvYCg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved now, the issue as @imtiaz said was from the severs side. And they solved it now. Thanks by the way for you support.